# Having trouble getting form_with to pass the :id as required by the path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am using form_with in a rails form.  The invocation of form_with uses both the url: and model: params, using the url to override the controller that would be the default for model.  What is passed in the form does not include the id of the target object, as I would expect from the code below.

```
<%= form_with(url: admin_ride_path(@ride), model: @ride, local: true) do |form| %>

form_with(url: admin_ride_path(@ride), model: @ride, local: true) do |form|
```

The form is submitted for an update to an existing record.  I would expect that the path for the submission would be

```
PATCH /admin_ride/7   (where 7 is the id of the ride)
```

but it instead sends to

```
PATCH /admin_ride
```

For which there is no route.

Comment: Can you post you link_to for this form?

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure, your `@ride` variable has `id` attribute which is not `nil`

[form_with](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/ActionView%2FHelpers%2FFormHelper:form_with) works in two ways.

**1. When the Model id is not set**

For example your model name is `User` and you have a `@user` variable in your view which is not saved in database(@user.id is `nil`).

In this case the form will be submitted to /users/ with `POST` method.

**2. When Model is id set**

When the `@user.id` is set(record exists in database) and `id` is e.g. 1

In this case, `form_with` will automatically be submitted at route /users/1 with `PATCH` request.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this myself.
The ActiveRecord instance provides a persisted? method, which the form_with helper uses to decide if the record has been saved to the database. If @ride is 'new'd without recently being saved or deleted, @ride.persisted? will return false, so the route used will be one without the id and method will be POST instead of PATCH, even if there is an id in the @ride variable.